# FB4.5 profile cumulative instances much bigger than really created

Tags: actionscript-3, profile, cumulative-sum

When I use flash profile on my project,I find class A's cumulative instances is keep increasing. But when I debug the project and add a breakpoint in the class A's constructor,it only stop once, which means the class A only create one instance. Is it a profile bug or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

If you have try/catch blocks or anonymous functions in that class you might see something like this as you code accesses that class.  The profiler just reports the AS object that was at the top of the call stack at the time something is allocated.